# UDP/datagram server will not receive packets from remote computer

Tags: node.js, electron, udp

I've created a UDP listening server in an Electron program using the UDP/datagram module. The socket is bound to my local IP address (not loopback) and port 8500. The socket functions run without error. The open socket can be seen in Process Explorer. I'm using Packet Sender on both the local and remote computers to send test packets. Those sent from the local machine are received, those sent from the remote computer are not.

My code is taken, virtually verbatim, from the Node.js documentation:

```
const dgram = require('dgram');
const server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(`server error:\n${err.stack}`);
    server.close();
});

server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
    console.log(`server got: ${msg} from ${rinfo.address}:${rinfo.port}`);
});

server.on('listening', () => {
    const address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP address:', address);
    console.log(`server listening ${address.address}:${address.port}`);
});

server.bind(8500, '192.168.2.64', () => {
    console.log('bind callback!');
});
```

Local computer: Windows 11
Remote computer: Windows 10
electron version: 23.2.4
node.js version: 18.14.2

Here's the console.log from startup:

```
UDP address: { address: '192.168.2.64', family: 'IPv4', port: 8500 }
server listening 192.168.2.64:8500
bind callback!
server got: Testing 1, 2, 3... from 192.168.2.64:8501
server got: Testing 1, 2, 3... from 192.168.2.64:8501
server got: Testing 1, 2, 3... from 192.168.2.64:8501
```

There is no response whatsoever to packets sent from the remote computer. There are no messages in the developer tools view.

I've disabled the firewalls on both computers. The two instances of Packet Sender can exchange messages. I can see the remotely sent packets in Wireshark. (Oddly, I cannot see the locally sent packets in Wireshark. Maybe my network card recognizes its own IP and treats it as a loopback. *edit -- this appears to be the case; when I use Wireshark's loopback capture I see these packets*)

Both computers are connected to an ethernet switch on my desk that is connected to our LAN.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bind the socket to 0.0.0.0. You haven't posted the sending code, and you haven't stated the IP address of the remote computer.

Comment: @user207421 -- Thanks for the feedback. Binding to 0.0.0.0 makes no difference. The sending in this case is being done by Packet Sender, a third party application. The IP of the remote computer is 192.168.2.170, though I think that is irrelevant as long as it's on the same sub-domain.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's working now and appears to have been a firewall problem after all. We are using ESET Endpoint Security.

I had disabled the firewalls previously, but tried again when implementing a TCP server. When the TCP worked I gave the UDP another shot and it was working too.

I can't say definitively what the problem was but I used ESET's network troubleshooting wizard to unblock the remote device and now both UDP and TCP are working as they should.

Thanks for reading.